# How do I turn off 'P' mode in U1/U2/U3 settings in my Nikon Z6?

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-z6

I am struggling to turn off the 'P' mode in my U1/U2/U3 settings in my Nikon Z6. I can't override the automatic adjustments that the camera is making. How do I turn it off?

Answer (score 3):

You need to be in another mode and then save the settings to U1/2/3 to overwrite them being in P mode. That will also overwrite other settings as well, so make sure they are set as desired first.